# Which one is correct

Tags: sentence, questions, who

A. "John gave the slogan". Make it an interrogative sentence with WH-word.

Which one is correct?

1. Who did give the slogan?
2. Who gave the slogan?

B. "Grandfather came to meet John". Make it an interrogative sentence with WH-word.

Which one is correct?

1. Who came to meet John?
2. Who did come to meet John?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Who did give the slogan?" and "Who did come to meet John?" are grammatically correct, but the "did" is unwarranted based on the original statement. It adds an uncalled for emphasis. "Who gave the slogan?" will elicit the answer "John gave the slogan." If on a test a student were asked to turn the statement "Paul is a pig," into a question, the correct answer would be "Is Paul a pig?" "Paul is indeed a pig," would be grammatically correct, but wrong. "Who gave the slogan?" and "Who came to meet John?" are correct.

This a subtler question than I originally thought, analogous to the simple but profound philosophical question, "What is good?" "What is 'correct?'"

Comment: It is used to add emphasis where required. / Please consider how appropriate a question is for ELU before giving an 'answer'.

Comment: If that is the case, this is certainly not suitable for ELU and shouldn't be answered.